# Unexpected behavior of getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, css, getboundingclientrect

[codepen](https://codepen.io/arboldesierto/pen/qBYmxYJ)

I am trying to position footer div at the bottom of the page which is maximum value of the bottom coordinates of menu and content divs (`Math.max(menu, content)`).

But `unfolding all three menus` (making menu bigger than content) this value becomes smaller than actual menu bottom value (and bigger than content bottom value).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to note, it's usually not recommended to construct page layouts using JS this way. You're likely to get more consistent results with CSS approaches like the [sticky footer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Sticky_footers) pattern.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, please do not just dup the code onto an external platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBoundingClientRect()` gives results [relative to the viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), so it's affected by the current scroll position. Notice that if you unfold the menus without scrolling down (e.g. unfold menu 3 first) then it works correctly.

You can add `window.scrollY` to the `bottom` values to get the true position relative to the top of the document.

Comment: Not substract, but `add`

Comment: quite right, sorry!